# mongodb data model design - embedded document only?

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I'm not sure if I have to use only embedded documents for this example:

1. I have a basic model for an user
2. Every user has multiple pages
3. Every page has multiple sessions
4. Every session has multiple actions

So it might look like this:

```
user = {
  'email': 'test@test.com',
  'pages': [
       {
          'name': 'best page',
          'sessions': [
              {
                 session_name: 'abc',
                 actions: [
                    {abc: 'def'},
                    {abc: 'def'}
                 ]
              },

          ]
       }, ..
  ]
};
```

Basically there are 3 nested arrays. Sessions data will be used just for reading (no update operation). I was thinking about making sessions as another model with reference on page. Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing absolutely fine with your architecture.This is the case of `one to many relationship`. You must keep `Sessions data` in `nested form` as illustrated in your example.Even if you want to just query sessions data, you might need to `issue multiple queries to resolve the references` in future. So,for better practice, you should not keep sessions data separately. For more information, see [Mongo: Model One-to-Many Relationships](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)